# What is the B5 pin for USB-C cable? Something wrong with Wikipedia?

Tags: usb, cables, wire, usb-c

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C) there seems to be inconsistency between the first and second tables: the first table says that B5 pin is for Configuration Channel, while the second table says that the B5 pin is for V_CONN power. What is exactly the B5 pin and the yellow wire for?

Answer (score 1):

There is no confusion, it's both depending on how the cable/receptacle is used.

See [Microchip USB-C AppNote](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/00001953a.pdf):

[image]

And further on in the document:

[image]

The cable can also be reconfigured to be things like DisplayPort in "Alternate Mode", which turns the CC1/CC2 pins into "VCONN" pins.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no inconsistency. There is Type-C receptacle, and there is Type-C plug.

Within a receptacle the A5 and B5 pins are Communication Channel pins.

In Type-C plug (cable), only one of CC pins has pull-up or pull-down, host/device "signature".

When the receptacle finds out which of CC pins has the "connect signal", the other CC pin becomes VCONN, to feed internal electronics inside the cable. Therefore in a cable one CC pin (A5) carries connect signature (and defines which data lanes to use), and the other symmetrical B5 pin is named "Vconn".

Comment: Nice one! So if B5 carries the config channel, then A5 becomes Vconn?

Comment: @HighGPA, just flip the connector 180 degree, and see yourself.